# Re Regular expression operations, remove periods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-re

I'm working with a function I made to split this sample line below to remove the standalone numerical values (123), however it's also removing the trailing numbers which I need. I also can't figure out how to remove the "0.0"

> ABC/0.0/123/TT1/1TT//

```
cleaned_data = []
def split_lines(lines, delimiter, remove = '[0-9]+$'):
  for line in lines:
    tokens = line.split(delimiter)
    tokens = [re.sub(remove, "", token) for token in tokens]
    clean_list = list(filter(lambda e:e.strip(), tokens))
    cleaned_data.append(clean_list)
    print(clean_list)
split_lines(lines, "/")
```

What's coming out now is below, notice the 0. and "TT" that's missing the trailing 1.

> [ABC], [0.], [TT], [1TT]

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to happen with non-numeric values that only contain numbers and decimal points (e.g. `1.2.3`), or with numeric values in the scientific notation (e.g. `1e+10`) or negative numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including the start of line anchor (^) as well.

```
cleaned_data = []
def split_lines(lines, delimiter, remove = '^[0-9.]+$'):
  for line in lines:
    tokens = line.split(delimiter)
    tokens = [re.sub(remove, "", token) for token in tokens]
    clean_list = list(filter(lambda e:e.strip(), tokens))
    cleaned_data.append(clean_list)
    print(clean_list)
split_lines(lines, "/")
```

I simply changed the default value of the `remove` parameter to '^[0-9.]+$' which only matches if the *entire* search string is numbers (or a period).

Comment: This worked! I was putting the line anchor (^) in the wrong spot. Thank you.

Comment: You can eliminate the second list comprehension and the filter step if you use the walrus operator to do it all in one loop: `cleaned_list = [t for token in line.split(delimiter) if (t := re.sub(remove, "", token))]`

Comment: Note that this regex will remove non-numeric values too (e.g. `1.2.3.4.5`, which is not a number). Mayve @Chaotic.Python should clarify whether these values need to be removed. (If not, then simply change the regex to `^\d*(?:\.\d+)?$`

Comment: Or negative values, in which case add an optional `-?` to the start.

Comment: Yes actually the numbers that have a period would always be in format "X.X" which I do not need removed.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need regular expressions? This job is much simpler if you just use `str.split()` and try to convert the resulting values to `float`:

```
def split_lines_remove_numeric(lines, delimiter):
    for line in lines:
        clean_list = []
        for item in line.split(delimiter):
            if not item: continue # Skip this item if it's empty
            try: 
                # Convert to float
                float(item)
            except ValueError: # Enter this block if conversion threw an error
                clean_list.append(item)
        print(clean_list)
```

Then, calling this function removes the values you want:

```
>>> split_lines_remove_numeric(["ABC/0.0/123/TT1/1TT//"], "/")
['ABC', 'TT1', '1TT']
```